# How to define the market and the clearance conditions of a general sectoral computable equilibrium model?

Tags: microeconomics, optimization, equilibrium

I am trying to implement a general multiproduct market (partial/sectoral) computable equilibrium model, where "general" refers to the fact that the relation of complementarity/substitutability between products is given in the data, through the cross elasticities, rather than defined in the model itself.

So, I have:

- a bunch of products $j$ of certain sector (in my specific case, timber products)
- a power functional form for both the demand and the supply functions:

  - $D_j = K_j \prod_i p_i^{\epsilon_{i,j}}$
  - $S_j = \tilde{K_j} \prod_i p_i^{\tilde{\epsilon_{i,j}}}$
- data in terms of the constant terms $K_j$ and $\tilde{K_j}$ and demand/supply elasticities in sparce matrices

I am trying to implement a computable model to numerically "solve" the above system, using JuMP/IPOPT.

My "first attempt" has been the following:

- define the non-negative variables demands $d_j$ and supply $s_j$ quantities, and relative prices $pd_j$ and $ps_j$
- define the constraints as

  - $d_j == K_j \prod_i p_i^{\epsilon_{i,j}}$
  - $s_j == \tilde{K_j} \prod_i p_i^{\tilde{\epsilon_{i,j}}}$
  - $pd_j == ps_j$
- define the objective function as $obj = \min (d_j - s_j)^2$

While the model "finds" a local optimum, the objective is not zero and some demands do not correspond to the corresponding supply quantities.

I have tried to change the equality of the supply or demand constraints to "greater or equal" or "less or equal" and in some cases, I get a zero objective value. Still, I wonder if any of these is correct or if it is just the solver finding a nice spot but without actually "clearing the market".

Which is the standard way to define the clearing conditions for a "general" multi-product market like this one ?